# Guardar datos en archivo de texto

Tags: c

He estado intentando que el resultado de mi código se guarde en un archivo de texto, pero ahora no me guarda, ni me deja agregar datos. Al principio, antes de intentar ponerle el FILE, sí me pedía los datos y me los imprimía en la consola, pero también necesito que se me guarden en un archivo de texto, y eso es lo que me está dando problemas.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define personas 3

struct datosp{
    char nombre[50];
    char apellido[];
    char direccion[];
    char telefono[];
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    
    int j,opc;
    FILE *arch = fopen("DatosPersonales.txt","j");
    
    if(arch){
        printf("Archivo de texto creado exitosamente...\n");
        struct datosp datos[personas];
        for(int j=0;j<personas;j++){
            printf("Digite el nombre:\t");
            scanf("%s",datos[j].nombre);
            printf("Digite el apellido:\t");
            scanf("%s",datos[j].apellido);
            printf("Digite la direccion:\t");
            scanf("%s",datos[j].direccion);
            printf("Digite el numero de telefono:/t");
            scanf("%s",datos[j].telefono);
        
    strncat(datos[j].nombre," | ",50);
    strncat(datos[j].nombre,datos[j].apellido, 50);
    strncat(datos[j].nombre," | ",50);
    strncat(datos[j].nombre,datos[j].direccion,50);
    strncat(datos[j].nombre," | ",50);
    strncat(datos[j].nombre,datos[j].telefono,50);
    
    printf("\n   %s \n", datos[j].nombre," | " ,datos[j].direccion);

    printf("\n Felicidades, los datos se han guardado exitosamente...\n");  
        
            printf("Si quiere terminar presione 1, sino presione 2");
            scanf("%d",&opc);
            
            if(opc==1){
                int j = 0;
                for(j;j<personas;j++){
                    fprintf(arch,"\n   %s \n", datos[j].nombre," | " ,datos[j].direccion);
                }
            }
            
            printf("Datos guardados exitosamente en el archivo de texto...");
    return 0;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: En resumen: _¿cuál es el problema?_ Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Fíjate que el código no está bien identado (no es necesario pero hace que se vea mejor) y que tienes llaves de más. Por cierto, `j`no es un modo válido. Usa `w` o `a` https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen

Comment: Ese código ni compila, los campos `apellido`, `direccion` y `telefono` no tienen un tamaño establecido.